# Query two collections with a related field and same value in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So basically what im trying to achieve is getting the participants documents for each event queried.Please view the image posted.both have a common EventId field that needs to be matched.The code below only works for the first iteration but immediately stops before getRealtimeChild().The Events doc has an Id field
[image: Events]
[image: Participants]

```
    useEffect(() => {

    //Fetch events ordered by timestamp
    const eventsRef = realDB.ref('Events').orderByChild('EventTimestamp').limitToFirst(3);

    setLoader(true);

    eventsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        //var o = 0;
        //var i = 0;
    //Fetch Participants of each events
        snapshot.forEach(function (events) {
            // console.log(events.key)
            // console.log('outer =>'  ,o+=1)

            getRealtimeChild('Participants', 'EventId', events.key).limitToLast(5).get().then(function (snapshot) {
                console.log(events.key)
                snapshot.forEach(function (p) {
                    // console.log('p =>',p.key)
                    // console.log('inner =>'  ,i+=1)

                    participants=[];
                    participants.push(p.val())
                    setParticipantList([])
                    setParticipantList(participants)
                    // console.log(participants)
                    // console.log(participantList)
                })
                eventList.push(Object.assign(events.val(),{id: events.key},{participants:participantList}));

                // console.log(participantList)


            });

        });

        setEventsList(eventList)
        setLoader(false);
        console.log(eventList)


    });

}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`equalTo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data) method to get participants of a specific event.

```
const ref = realDB.ref('Events/Participants')
const snapshot = await ref.orderByChild('EventId').equalTo('<EVENT-ID>').once("value")
console.log(snapshot.val());
```

You can additionally use `limitToFirst` or `limitToLast` methods as per your needs.

| method | description |
| --- | --- |
| limitToFirst | Sets the maximum number of items to return from the beginning of the ordered list of results. |
| limitToLast | Sets the maximum number of items to return from the end of the ordered list of results. |